# My data is displaying incorrectly. Jade and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I've managed to query data from Twitch api, however this data is displaying randomly and incorrectly. I've been assuming this problem is due to something i have done wrong with my angular. This is my Jade html:

```
main(ng-app='heyTwitch')
  section(ng-controller='MainCtrl')
    header
      ul#mainMenu
        li

    ul#people(ng-repeat='user in getdata')
      li
        a(href='http://twitch.tv/{{user[0]["data"].display_name}}' target='_blank') {{user[0]["data"].display_name}}

        img(ng-src='{{user[0]["data"].logo}}' err-src='http://placehold.it/50x50').pic
```

This is my javascript snippet where my data is processed:

```
function addData(username) {
    var temp = [];
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + username + "?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function() {}).done(function(data) {
      if (data.stream === null) {
        url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + username + "?callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          temp.push({"username":username, "data":data,"status": false});
          count--;
          if (count === 0) {
            //temp = temp.sort();
          }
        });
      } else {
        temp.push({"username":username, "data":data,"status": false});
        count--;
        if (count === 0) {
          //temp = temp.sort();
        }
      }
      $scope.getdata.push(temp);
      $scope.getdata.sort;
      console.log($scope.getdata);
      $scope.$apply();
    })
  }
```

What I'm I doing wrong that my data is not displaying properly?
My entire app is here : http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/EjONEe

Comment: Side Note: do convert `$.ajax` to `$http` will run digest for you automatically

Comment: @PankajParkar I've been thinking about doing that but I have doubts on how to do it. Should I simply change $.getJSON to $http and leave the parameters the same?

Comment: Codepen link is not working :(

Comment: @gusper oops, try now..

Comment: What do you mean by "data is not displaying properly"? Could you please specify what the problem is?

Comment: First of all, my whole list of usernames is not displayed, they are displaying randomly. Secondly, my data is displayed disproportionately(white spaces). @gusper

Comment: But my main issue is that all my users are not displayed, just random fragments(only 3 or 4 when it should be more..) of them each time i run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the repeat should be at the `li` element instead of the `ul` element:

```
li#people(ng-repeat='user in getdata')
```

This will make one `ul` element with many `li` elements instead of one `ul` and one `li` element for each player. (Note: you will have to update your css to match this.)

Secondly it's better to use a dictionary than a list for the temp object:

```
var temp = {};
```

and then set the temp values like this:

```
temp = {
    "username": username,
    "data": data,
    "status": false
};
```

Instead of:

```
a(href='http://twitch.tv/{{user[0]["data"].display_name}}' target='_blank') {{user[0]["data"].display_name}}
```

it should now look like this (the [0] removed):

```
a(href='http://twitch.tv/{{user.data.display_name}}' target='_blank') {{user.data.display_name}}
```

When you add the temp element to `$scope.getdata` you have to do this in the correct place. If the "streams" is null and you are making another request for the "channels", then you will have to add the temp object to the list in the response handler for the "channels" request. You can do something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('heyTwitch', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    var users = ["freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "notmichaelmcdonald", "RobotCaleb", "medrybw", "comster404", "brunofin", "thomasballinger", "joe_at_underflow", "noobs2ninjas", "mdwasp", "beohoff", "xenocomagain"];

    var count = 0;
    count = users.length;

    $scope.getdata = [];

    users.map(function(user) {
        addData(user);

    })

    function addData(username) {
        var temp = {};
        var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + username + "?callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url, function() {}).done(function(data) {
            if (data.stream === null) {
                console.log("Stream is null for " +username);
                url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + username + "?callback=?";
                $.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
                    addPlayer(username, data);
                });
            } else {
                addPlayer(username, data);
            }
        })
    }

    //Add player to list of players
    function addPlayer(username, data){
        //TODO: Check that data is valid here
        var temp = {
            "username": username,
            "data": data,
            "status": false
        };        
        $scope.getdata.push(temp);
        $scope.$apply();        
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and detailing my mistakes. However, after using your method(I agree is much better than mine, especially converting my temp to dict), my data does not display.. Here's my codepen again http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/EjONEe. Maybe there's a silly mistake I'm making..

Comment: Nevermind, i got it to work! Thank you so much. Now I'm having displaying blank user, but I'll work on that..http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/EjONEe

Comment: Some of the players didn't return correct data, there were an error, so before pushing a player to the getdata array should probably do some validation.